# I want to display user image on my index.html {{ user.UserProfileInfo.profile_pic.url }}

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
    class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
        profile_pic = 
        models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    
   def __str__(self):
     return self.user.username
```

[and here is how i tried to use it in my profile.html]

src="{{ info.profile_pic.url }}"

below is my views

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    data = {
        "info":UserProfileInfo.objects.get()
    }
    return render(request,'dappx/profile.html', data)
```

I'm ready and willing to upload any other snippet of my code if needed.
any help will be greatly appreciated thanks in advance

I'm trying to display the user's image on my profile.html template

Here is the error i am currently getting:
MultipleObjectsReturned at /dappx/profile/
get() returned more than one UserProfileInfo -- it returned 6!

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: "I'm trying to display the user's image on my index.html template" - okay, so **how did you try** using the code? **What happened** when you tried doing that, and **how is that different** from what you want?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close, but the default [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for a [**`OneToOneField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) is the name of the "source model", in *lowercase*, so:

```
{{ user.userprofileinfo.profile_pic.url }}
```

with as view, simply:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'dappx/profile.html')
```

Comment: It worked on my localhost but after deploying to pythonanywhere the profile pictures is not showing again and all other static files are working

Comment: @JaiyeOlu: these are not static files, but media files, you thus need to configure nginx to also serve the media files.